# How to keep android running after call comming?

Tags: android, call

My  app seems stopped after a phone call comming, How to keep it running and keep the state before the call?

Comment: Do you understand the Android activity lifecycle? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html

Answer (score 2):

When your app is running, and you receive a phone call, your App should save the app current state by overriding

```
onPause() {
    //save your state here
}
```

methods, and implement

```
onResume() {
    //load your state here
}
```

Comment: if my app use some thread to receive information, when a call comming, the thread will stop or not ? Did I need restart these thread ?

Comment: yes, the good practice is to stop any thread from running when the application is paused, and recreating/restarting them when the onResume method is called

Comment: @GodwinW Great answer, helped me as well :)

Answer (score 1):

May you can use PhoneStateListener to start your previous Activity after call end.

```
class CallEndedListener extends PhoneStateListener {
        boolean called = false;

        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);

            if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK)
                called = true;

            if (called && state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
                called = false;
                // do something here.
            }
        }
    }
```